# Why does if statement iteration return ambiguous series bool?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, iteration, valueerror

I'm quite new to python. I am trying to iterate through list columns using an 'if' statement with 2 conditions. The return statement I keep getting is *"The truth value of a Series is ambiguous (when iterating through a series using if statement"*

Below is my code (the data frame consists of app data from Google Play Store)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("googleplaystore.csv")
df.tail()

df["Rating"].fillna(value = '0.0', inplace= True)

medical_app_ratings = []

for row in df[1:]:
    rating = df.Rating
    genre = df.Genres
    if genre == "Medical":
        medical_app_ratings.append(rating)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-51c7806c01da> in <module>
      5     rating = df.Rating
      6     genre = df.Genres
----> 7     if genre == "Medical":
      8         medical_app_ratings.append(rating).bool()
      9 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1477     def __nonzero__(self):
   1478         raise ValueError(
-> 1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1481         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

If anyone could please tell me what I am doing wrong I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: You want: `df.loc[df['Genres'] == 'Medical', 'Rating']`. When working with dataframes, try to get rid of the idea of `iterating` and use the vectorized methods provided by pandas and numpy.

Comment: [caveats-and-gotchas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/gotchas.html#caveats-and-gotchas)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to iterate through the dataframe, and I recommend to use `df.iterrows()` to accomplish it.

Here is an example on how to use it:

```
medical_app_ratings = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
  rating = row.Rating
  genre = row.Genres
  if genre == "Medical":
    medical_app_ratings.append(rating)
```